# Office365 graph task push notifications issue

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

We are using this graph [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create a subscription. For the task delete event we are not receiving any notification from Microsoft. We are receiving notifications for creating and updating the same task. Please advise on this.